# Authentication in a Mongo Sharded Cluster

Tags: authentication, replication, mongodb, sharding

I have a mongo shared cluster and replica sets:

**The ShardA Replica set:**

```
A1. 10.77.14.241 

A2. 10.77.14.242

AA. 10.77.14.243 Arbiter
```

Some parameters of /etc/mongod.conf:

```
#bind_ip=127.0.0.1
auth=true
replSet=ShardB
keyFile=/srv/mongodb/mongodb-keyfile
```

**The ShardB Replica set:**

```
B1. 10.77.14.244 

B2. 10.77.14.245

BA. 10.77.14.246 Arbiter
```

Some parameters of /etc/mongod.conf:

```
#bind_ip=127.0.0.1
auth=true
replSet=ShardB
keyFile=/srv/mongodb/mongodb-keyfile
```

**The Config and Mongos servers:**

```
C1. 10.77.14.247

C2. 10.77.14.248

C3. 10.77.14.249
```

All instances of config mongod and mongos are started in /etc/rc.local:

```
mongod --configsvr  --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --keyFile /srv/mongodb/mongodb-keyfile --fork
mongos --configdb 10.77.14.247:27019,10.77.14.248:27019,10.77.14.249:27019 --port 40000 --logpath /data/mongos.log --keyFile /srv/mongodb/mongodb-keyfile --fork
```

The Replica sets work correctly. If I insert documents in the primary member it replicates on the secondary member.

I have following issue:
On any arbiter, mongod config, mongos -

```
use admin   
switched to db admin    
mongos> db.auth({user: 'admin', pwd: '12345678'})    
Error: 18 Authentication failed.
0
```

Hence i can't insert documents to a DB over mongos.

Do I have to enable a sharding of the admin a DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reread http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication-without-bypass/ :)

1) I started on the C1, C2, C3:

```
mongod --configsvr  --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --fork
mongos --configdb 10.77.14.247:27019,10.77.14.248:27019,10.77.14.249:27019 --port 40000 --logpath /data/mongos.log --fork
```

2) I created a new user on mongos:

```
use admin
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "admin",
      pwd: "12345678",
      roles: [
         { role: "clusterManager", db: "admin" },
         { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }
      ]
    }
)
```

3) I restarted instances of the mongod config and mongos --keyfile parameter:

```
  mongod --configsvr  --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log --fork --keyFile /srv/mongodb/mongodb-keyfile
mongos --configdb 10.77.14.247:27019,10.77.14.248:27019,10.77.14.249:27019 --port 40000 --logpath /data/mongos.log --fork --keyFile /srv/mongodb/mongodb-keyfile
```

4) Adding Shards was succesful:

```
db.auth({user:'admin', pwd: '12345678'})
1

sh.addShard("ShardA/10.77.14.241:27017,10.77.14.242:27017,10.77.14.243:27017")
{ "shardAdded" : "ShardA", "ok" : 1 }

sh.addShard("ShardB/10.77.14.244:27017,10.77.14.245:27017,10.77.14.246:27017")
{ "shardAdded" : "ShardB", "ok" : 1 }
```

Comment: Very good and simple explanation. Hope MongoDB docs had this.